# Theorem environment to start on the same line as itemize symbol

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, itemize, theorems, newtheoremstyle

In my document, I want to have an `itemize` environment. Within this environment I want to give a `definition` (which was previously defined). Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Language support
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Math support
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Definition of definition
\newtheoremstyle{myStyle}
{}                % Space above
{}                % Space below
{\upshape}        % Theorem body font % (default is "\upshape")
{}                % Indent amount
{\bfseries}       % Theorem head font % (default is \mdseries)
{:}               % Punctuation after theorem head % default: no punctuation
{ }               % Space after theorem head
{}                % Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{myStyle}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
    I want to give two different definitions which will turn out to be equivalent.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{definition}
            This is the first definition.
        \end{definition}
        
        \item \begin{definition}
            This is the second definition.
        \end{definition}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which yields
[image]

I do not like that *Definition 1* and the counter *1.* are not on the same line. Does someone know a way to get around this?

Thank you in advance and since this is my first time posting, please let me know if I should provide more (or less) information.